Computing effective sample size in tensorflow - Complex128 Warning
When computing the effective sample size of a NumPy array as done below
import numpy as np
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

x = np.random.randn(1000, 2, dtype=np.float64)
ess = tfp.mcmc.effective_sample_size(x)

I get the following cryptic warning:
WARNING:tensorflow:You are casting an input of type complex128 to an incompatible dtype float64.  This will discard the imaginary part and may not be what you intended.

How can I fix this?

@user24714692 I am trying to compute the ESS for each column of x. I have also tried to explicitly set the datatype of x to be np.float64 (which is the default anyways with np.random.randn) so I don't know where Tensorflow is getting the complex128 from...

Try arviz?

@user24714692 I have tried but it does not seem reliable in the sense that the ESS is way too high. Here is my MWE:
import numpy as np
from arviz import ess, convert_to_dataset

x = np.random.randn(12, 1000, 2)  # 12 chains, 1000 samples, 2 dims
np.array(ess(convert_to_dataset(x)).to_array())

This code produces ESS that is well above 1000

